# General programmatic| difficulty in solving programmatic issue

Tags: c#, database

I am having a difficulty to solve a problem:
those are the object that I have in my solution

> Investigator
> and a
> Book

Investigator write a book.

Both of them have a class, what I am trying to achieve is that functionality:(2 things)

Book that have more then 1 Investigator that wrote him. (1 book -> more then one Investigator )
And Investigator that write more then one book.

### Data-Base

I have 2 tables one for Investigator and one for Book

What I thought that I need to add is:

```
public class Investigator{
...
public int[] Books { get; set; } //the books that the investigator wrote
}

public class Book{
...
public int[] investigators { get; set; } //the investigators that wrote the book
}
```

But then I didn't know what to do, in the database, add a column that will contain more then one value?  (this can't be done) so what are the alternative?

---

After reading the answers here
[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NA5bv78mmQM) help me to understand it.

Comment: [Many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship, pay attention to junction table part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in a many-many relationship you will have three database tables. In this case you would have a table for investigators, a table for books and a table with investigators and books with a column for investigator IDs and a column for book IDs, with the primary key being the combination of the two.

I have however seen people who have done it with two tables by having fields with a list of IDs separated by commas  - so the table for books would have an investigators column with, for example, '2,5,6' and investigators would have a books column.

With the second version you would have to deal with the commas programmatically and it could get quite messy if someone has written a lot of books so I wouldn't recommend it. There's a reason the first option is standard practice.

Comment: Definitely go for the former solution. The latter will only cause confusion.

Comment: Agreed with Yuval. Do NOT do the comma-separated thing. That's a terrible DB design. Go with the first one.

Comment: Can you please post a link to an example?

Comment: @Alpar, nope:) I have edited my question and posted a video that helped. thanks